# maven surefire reporting plugin configuration

Tags: java, maven-2, surefire

I have a multi-module maven project.  The parent pom.xml is simply a way to reference common information for the 4 subprojects.   I have quite a few JUnit tests that run and I also have the Parent Project set up for Project WebSite using the **maven-info-reports-plugin**.

I have the **maven-surefire-report-plugin** configured in the parent and it generates the ***target/site/surefire-report.html*** file in each of the subprojects with the correct information.

My problem is when I run my project website via **site:run** I do not see any of the ***surefire-report.html*** files in the Project website.  The one that shows is in the target directory of the parent and it has no unit tests defined.

Is there a way I can configure **maven-surefire-report-plugin** or **maven-info-reports-plugin** to aggregate the subprojects generated surefire reports?

Answer (score 36):

To elaborate on Seph's answer. You can set many of the Maven reports to aggregate results. To do this with the surefire-report plugin you'd do something like this:

```
<reporting>
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-surefire-report-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>2.4.2</version>
      <configuration>
        <aggregate>true</aggregate>
        <!--also set this to link to generated source reports-->
        <linkXRef>true</linkXRef>
      </configuration>
    </plugin>
  </plugins>
</reporting>
```

Note the additional linkXRef property, this allows you to add cross-references to the generated html version of the source produced by the [jxr plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-jxr-plugin/jxr-mojo.html). The jxr plugin can also be set to aggregate, so the two combined allow you to browse your entire project structure.

As far as I know, the maven-info-reports-plugin doesn't do aggregation.

Comment: Excellent that worked.  Thank you very much you saved me a lot of investigative time.   I love Stackoverflow.com

Comment: Don't forget to "Accept" the answer that solved your problem. This answer also helped me so I would like the poster to get proper credit.

Comment: @PeterDelaney Even if quite late can you accept the answer of Rich?

Answer (score 2):

You can add

```
<aggregate>true</aggregate>
```

to the surefire plugin in the parent pom.xml.

Answer (score 1):

**For command line**

```
mvn surefire-report:report -Daggregate=true
```

It could be -

```
mvn clean test -fn surefire-report:report  -Daggregate=true
OR
mvn clean install -fn surefire-report:report  -Daggregate=true
```

Note : 
`fn` -> NEVER fail the build, regardless of project result

**To add in pom**

```
<aggregate>true</aggregate>
```