# Maven surefire test results for a project with various modules

Tags: maven, junit, report, surefire

I've a parent pom project with various submodules. I want to get a report of the unit tests results but using surfire plugin, I get an independent result for each module.

I mean, if I execute:

```
mvn surefire-report:report
```

from the parent directory where the parent pom is located, it creates a surefire-report.html for each subproject but what I want, is only one html with the results of all the subprojectes.

Is there any way to achieve this automatically? Using surefire or some other plugin.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

To create the `aggregate report` please try to use the following command at the`parent project`.

```bsh
mvn surefire-report:report -Daggregate=true
```

I hope this may help.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/1276317/768795 for how to configure this in the POM.

Comment: Just note that the report will be in `/target/site/surefire-report.html`